# Матрица в классе не инициализируеться с помощью конструктора в main, C#

Tags: c#, матрицы, конструктор

Поле класса `numbers` - двумерний массив. В классе создал конструктор, который инициализирует этот массив случайными значениями (`Array(int columns, int rows)`). После того как вызвал конструктор в `Main` (Program.cs) массив не инициализировался, хотя при пошаговой отладке видно что он инициализировался.

Array.cs

```
public class Array
{
    int[,] numbers;
    int columns, rows;
    int result = 0;
    public Array()
    {

    }
    public Array(int columns, int rows)
    {
        this.columns = columns;
        this.rows = rows;
        int[,] numbers = new int[this.rows, this.columns];
        Random range = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.columns; j++)
            {
                numbers[i, j] = range.Next(1, 100);
                Console.Write(numbers[i, j] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }

    }
```

Program.cs:

```
Array array = new Array(3, 3);
```

[image: После выполнения етого кода в окне локальние показываеться что в массиве все значения нули, хотя в консоли выводятся норм значения:]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[,] numbers = ...
```

В вышеуказанной строке вы создаёте новую переменную `numbers` и присваеваете ей значение, вместо того чтобы присвоить значение существующему полю. Уберите `int[,]`. В результате код будет выглядить так:

```
...
this.rows = rows;
numbers = new int[this.rows, this.columns]; // <------
Random range = new Random();
...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)